# python sdk query_job.result() fail to poll job status

Tags: python, google-bigquery

google-cloud-bigquery version is 1.5.0 and the stack crashed in sdk code. is there any workaround?

`[2018-09-12 21:18:01,265] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     query_job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish
...
[2018-09-12 21:18:01,315] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
[2018-09-12 21:18:01,316] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/fsql-production/queries/[my job id]?maxResults=0: Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1534808046936000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field request_started_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates an error in your query, not in the client code. The error is:

> Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1534808046936000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field request_started_at

It sounds like you have a field/column named `request_started_at` that is scaled incorrectly; `1534808046936000000` should probably be `1534808046936000`. There is some material related to this in the [guide on migrating to standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#timestamp_differences). If all the values of this column are scaled incorrectly, then you can do something like this to fix them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE dataset.table AS
SELECT *
  REPLACE (TIMESTAMP_MICROS(DIV(UNIX_MICROS(request_started_at), 1000)) AS request_started_at)
FROM dataset.table
```

This replaces the values in the column after scaling them down by a factor of 1000.